# How to handle authentication on multiple navigators (react-navigation) in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Here is my tab navigator present in `MainNavigator.js`,

```
const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'Home'}
        component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'About'}
        component={About} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={'Profile'}
        component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  ) 

}
```

I have an `AuthNavigator.js` which includes a stack navigator,

```
const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name={'Login'} component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'Signup'} component={Signup} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}
```

So, I have a logout button on my Profile Screen in Tab Navigator. I want to Navigate to Login Screen in `AuthNavigator` with the `onPress` event. Here is how I tried this,

```
const Profile = ({navigation}) => {
  const logoutHandler = () => {
   navigation.navigate('Login');
  }

<SafeAreaView>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={logoutHandler}>
    <Text>Logout</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</SafeAreaView>
}
```

However, this is not working. As a beginner to React Native I have no idea how to link this `Login` route into a Stack screen. Really appreciate it if somebody could save my day. Thankyou so much.

Comment: Where are you using `MainNavigator` and `AuthNavigator `.

Comment: Because Main Navigator is my bottom tab navigator and AuthNavigator is my Stack Screens for Login and Register

Comment: I'm asking at what point you've used MainNavigator, I'll update my answer accordingly. The ideal approach for managing AUTH and UNAUTH route that I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Manage 1 state globally (using redux or some other state management tool) and that is `isAuthenticated`.
2. Then in your `App.js` or where ever you have defined your root navigator do the changes likewise : -

```
       <NavigationContainer>
           { isAuthenticated ? <AuthRoutes /> : <UnAuthRoute />
       </NavigationContainer>
```

3. On login and logout you'll have to update this isAuthenticated state and then routes will be taken care as per the state

Comment: I just want to redirect user to the Login route when he/she clicks the logout button

Comment: If you will do likewise and update this state `isAuthenticated` it will auto redirect to your `AuthRoute` or `UnAuthRoute` as per your state.

Comment: I'm not expecting this conditional statement cause I have already stated conditional routes, So this could break my code. I'm expecting to redirect onPress event

Comment: then add 1 screen in your `AuthNavigator.js`  stack likewise `<Stack.Screen name={'MainNavigatore'} component={MainNavigator} />`, Then your navigate statement will work.

Comment: Thanks I rebuild my project as you said it is much simple.